# how to set dynamically value to the webos IntegerPicker

Tags: webos

How do I set value dynamically to the integerpicker?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First insert a interpicker to your html scene:

```
<div x-mojo-element="IntegerPicker" id="integerpickerId" class="integerpickerClass" name="integerpickerName"></div>
```

Then instantiate the picker in the Scene-assistant.js file in the setup function:

```
MainSceneAssistant.prototype.setup = function() {

    this.controller.setupWidget("integerpickerId",
             this.attributes = {
                 label: 'Number',
                 modelProperty: 'value',
                 min: 0,
                 max: 20

             },
             this.integerPickerModel = {
                 value: 5
             });}
```

You can than change the picker dynamically by setting the model:

```
this.integerPickerModel.value = 10;
this.controller.modelChanged(this.integerPickerModel, this);
```

This works for the most widgets in webos, like pickers and textfields.